# Argument Out of Range issues using FMX TListBox

Tags: delphi, listbox, delphi-xe7, delphi-xe8

I'm using a `TListBox` in Firemonkey, and I'm facing a strange issue when it comes to dynamically showing/hiding items. This includes both Delphi XE7 and XE8. The setup, there is a `TPopupBox` at the top of the form, where user chooses one of the items listed. Depending on which was chosen, the `TListBox` should show only certain `TListBoxItem`s, and hide the rest. Part of this consists of resizing each list item height to 0 when not visible (otherwise it would leave an ugly gap between the items).

The problem is that very randomly and spontaneously (no pattern), selecting an item in this `TPopupBox` (calling `OnChange` which modifies visibility), produces an `EArgumentOutOfRangeException` at an unknown point. The code breaks in `System.Generics.Collections.TListHelper.SetItemN()` on the first line calling `CheckItemRangeInline(AIndex);` Within there, it's simply:

```
procedure TListHelper.CheckItemRangeInline(AIndex: Integer);
begin
  if (AIndex < 0) or (AIndex >= FCount) then
    raise EArgumentOutOfRangeException.CreateRes(@SArgumentOutOfRange);
end;
```

The exception continues to be raised over and over and over again with no end (starts with 4 in a row). When I use the debugger to step in, I can never manage to get it to happen.

There are a couple common procedures used here which control item visibility:

```
//lstTrans = TListBox

//Iterates through all items and hides everything
procedure TfrmMain.HideTransItems;
var
  X: Integer;
begin
  for X := 0 to lstTrans.Count-1 do begin
    lstTrans.ListItems[X].Visible:= False;
  end;
end;

//Sets height of visible items to 42, invisible items to 0
procedure TfrmMain.ResetTransHeights;
var
  X: Integer;
  LI: TListBoxItem;
begin
  for X := 0 to lstTrans.Count-1 do begin
    LI:= lstTrans.ListItems[X];
    if LI.Visible then
      LI.Height:= 42
    else
      LI.Height:= 0;
  end;
end;
```

Then, when choosing something in the `TPopupBox`:

```
//cboTrans = TPopupBox

procedure TfrmMain.cboTransChange(Sender: TObject);
  procedure E(AItem: TListBoxItem);
  begin
    AItem.Visible:= True;
  end;
begin
  HideTransItems; //Make all list items invisible
  case cboTrans.ItemIndex of
    0: begin
      E(lbSomeListBoxItem);
      E(lbSomeOtherItem);
      //More calls to "E"
    end;
    1: begin
      E(lbSomeListBoxItem2);
      //More calls to "E"
    end;
    //More indexes
  end;
  ResetTransHeights; //Adjust visible list item heights to be seen
end;
```

(The full procedure is just a lot of the exact same types of calls, too much to post here)

1. Nowhere am I adding or removing items - only changing visibility
2. There are no events triggered which might be causing some faulty loop
3. The `TPopupBox` is located outside of the `TListBox`
4. Each `TListBoxItem` has one or two controls (yet it doesn't matter which ones are being shown/hidden)
5. Selecting an item in this `TPopupBox` may work one time, yet fail the next
6. Sometimes it occurs the first time I show/hide these items, sometimes it takes 20-30 tries
7. Never able to reproduce while stepping through in Debug

Why would I be receiving this exception, and how do I fix it?

Comment: Did you try the same with D10Seattle? There have been some bugs within TList.

Comment: Some more info about bugs in TList here: https://plus.google.com/103246155735524926641/posts/Yne5Nv6mp6B

Comment: @LURD I haven't tried 10 yet, but I originally was working in XE7 when I started having this issue. That `TList<T>` bug apparently arose in XE8.

Comment: An ugly fix which seems to be working is that instead of setting the heights to `0`, I'm setting them to `0.01`.

Comment: After hours of no issues, I changed it back to `0` and it started again. No pattern at all here otherwise.

Comment: Not specific to your code, but related to the error...  I found that when SpellCheck is enabled for a TMemo, a misspelled word with red squiggles under it throws the same error "Argument out of range" when that text is deleted.  For instance, type `tht` on line 2 of a TMemo, then select all and delete.  "Argument out of range" = OSX runtime error 231.  I have reported this bug to Embarcadero.

Answer (score 1):

> Why would I be receiving this exception, and how do I fix it?

You know why you are receiving it. You are accessing an array with an index that lies outside the valid range.

The question is where that index is. If you cannot readily reproduce then you need to debug to gather diagnostics. On Windows you'd use a tool like madExcept to gather information. Most useful would be the call stack that led to the error.

If you don't have madExcept or a similar tool at hand use trace logging. Instrument your code so that it logs information that allows you to determine which access of the list is out of bounds. You'll likely end up iterating around this as you narrow down the search.

Finally, once you identify which code leads to the error, usually the problem becomes apparent.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when I was animating the height of a TListBoxItem.
The issue only occurred when I was changing the *Height* of a ***Selected*** item. I implemented [Jerry Dodge's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/988445/jerry-dodge) solution of setting the height to 0.01 instead of 0 which fixed the issue.

**Delphi Berlin Code**

```
    {Delphi Berlin}
    ItemIndex := 0;
    Item      := ListBox.ItemByIndex(ItemIndex);
    Height    := Item.Height;

    FloatAnimation              := TFloatAnimation.Create(nil);
    FloatAnimation.Parent       := Item;
    FloatAnimation.PropertyName := 'height'
    FloatAnimation.StartValue   := Height;
    FloatAnimation.StopValue    := 0.01; {Setting to 0 causes "Argument out of range" if the item is selected}
    FloatAnimation.Start;
```